# Google Analytics 4 - simple example of service account API usage in Java?

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I've spent a few days trying to get an example of how to do the above - use a service account to non-interactively get Google Analytics metrics using the GA4 API from Java.

The official example at

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java#3_setup_the_sample

has a requirement that you need to provide a "view ID" when initializing the GA4 client classes.

Nowhere can I find a "view ID" -anywhere- in my GA4 profile. I do have the JSON file with my credentials, have connected the GA4 property, created a service account, etc.

View IDs seems to be something used previously with Universal Analytics, which was discontinued 1 July 2023.

Additionally, what is the difference between "Reporting" and "Data" APIs in Google Analytics?

I've also found an official Google example of the "Data" API at

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

but there is a step that refers to setting an environment variable to define where to find the authentication JSON file - but where / how is an environment variable set in a headless JAR that will run on a different machine than where the JAR is being compiled (headless Linux server)?

How can I set the credentials JSON file location in the code (NOT an environment variable) per the data API example?

Trying to accomplish this in a Java Spring Maven App in NetBeans.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
GoogleCredential gc = GoogleCredential.FromStream(Utility.GetStreamFromResourceFile("C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\credentials.json", GetType()));
BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =       BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(gc)).build();
BetaAnalyticsDataClient betaAnalyticsDataClient =      BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the GoogleCredential class is marked deprecated?

Comment: Typical,  every time i get a working sample they deprecate something.  I will see if i can find sometime to work out a new sample.

Comment: Hi Linda found a workaround for this, see my answer below. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: where are you seeing that its deprecated im not seeing it here

Comment: The deprecated code was indicated with struck-through text in the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Strange that i am not seeing anything in intelij

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question's core issue, e.g.

*How can I set the credentials JSON file location in the code (NOT an environment variable) per the data API example?*

Was this code:

```
GoogleCredentials gc = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"))
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));

            BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings = BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(gc)).build();

            BetaAnalyticsDataClient betaAnalyticsDataClient = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings);
```

with my client_secrets.json file located in my NetBeans Maven project tree at the location

```
Projectname
 |
  src
   |
   resources
    |
    client_secrets.json
```

and my imports for the above is:

```
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataSettings;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.DateRange;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Dimension;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Metric;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportRequest;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportResponse;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
```

with this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.verishare</groupId>
    <artifactId>WPAnalyticsHelper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    
    <!--Spring-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!--Log4J-->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--Google APIs Java client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analyticsreporting</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev20190318-1.28.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev134-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.analytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-analytics-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.33.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev58-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.verishare.wpanalyticshelper.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/</link>
                        <link>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/${project.http.version}/</link>
                    </links>
                    <doctitle>${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle>
                    <windowtitle>${project.artifactId} ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Automatic-Module-Name>google.api.client.java6</Automatic-Module-Name>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-DocURL>https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/${project.version}/index.html</Bundle-DocURL>
                        <Bundle-Description>Java 6 extensions to the Google APIs Client Library for Java</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.google.api.client.java6</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>source-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <!--Set minimum requirement to Java 7-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java17</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                             
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

E. g. using the above I was able to reference my GA4 API credentials client_secrets.json file by direct reference in the code and not via an implied environment variable.